# BASH, SQLITE3, APACHE2 - bash script with different results depending on user?

Tags: bash, sqlite, debian, apache2

Ok, usually I don't give up that easy but this problem is starting to drive me nuts :-/

I have a BASH script that inserts lines into a SQLITE3 DB running on a Debian Server on AWS. The default user is "admin" and when I run the script it successfully adds the lines to the DB. However, the exact same script can be run by opening a specific webpage on that same server running Apache2, basically a cgi-bin script that calls the bash-script. The Apache2 user is "www-data" (all AWS Debian and Apache2 default installations!).
The problem is: the data that ends up in the same SQLITE3 db, the same table, the same fields (it IS the same script!) is not identical!
When run in terminal as "admin" a "good" string in the table looks like this:
'Reclaiming the land': Indigenous fight against Line 3 ramps up...   OR
Lobster diver survives after being caught 'in a whale's mouth'...

But when the script is launched via the webpage by Apache2 the result is this:
'''Reclaiming the land''': Indigenous fight against Line 3 ramps up...    OR
Lobster diver survives after being caught '''in a whale'''s mouth'''...

I know that Apostrophe need "special" treatment but it is the same script that works and not works. It has to be something user-specific but I can't figure out which setting is causing this.
I "played" around with all kind of environment variables in Apache, and in the bash script with no success.

I tried to start the bash script with

```
export LC_ALL="UTF-8" 
export LANG="$LC_ALL"
```

And I changed  settings in `/etc/apache2/envvars` (the following is the default, and of course I restarted Apache2 after changing settings):

```
## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
export LANG=C
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
#. /etc/default/locale
```

Additional infos:
The cgi-bin script calls a script using setsid:

```
setsid "/home/"$pathOnHost"/RSS/RSS_Control.sh" &> /dev/null &
```

Is the "environment" messed up here? And if so, how can I fix it??

RSS_Control.sh is inserting the values into the db like:

```
result_rowid=$( sqlite3 -cmd ".timeout "$sql_timeout "$RSS_DB_Filename" "insert into rss_titles ( Feed_ID, Published, Updated, Title, etc. )        \
              values( \"$RSS_Feed_ID\", \"$RSS_Published\", etc.) ...
```

Well, as I said, everythings works perfectly fine as long as I launch it manually in a bash terminal. The same scripts and code launched/run via a Browser-->Apache2-->cgi-bin-->bash do not work perfectly. Any ideas??

Comment: Maybe the first thing to do is split the pb, either the collect pf the data, either the insert in the db ... let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, isolated the problem. Don't really understand what's going on but at least I now know WHAT is causing the problem (and I can try to figure out a solution...).
I have a small function that removes some "special characters" from strings:

```
function removeSpecialChars () {
    local _resultvar=$1                             # contains the name of our variable
    local _content                                  # will contain the contents of our variable
    local _output                                   # will contain the contents of our variable
    eval  _content=$_resultvar                      # get the content and store it

    _output=${_content//[\"\„’\‘]/\'}               # We start with _content and continue with the _result for the rest

##  ...more stuff going on here... ##
    
    _output=$( echo ${_output}|sed "s/\x09/ /g" )   # Special Character Hex 09 ???

    eval  ${_resultvar:1}=\"'$_output'\"        # set the return variable to our result content
}



## Downloading stuff from the web... ###


    temp=${allTitles[articleIdx]}
    removeSpecialChars "$temp"


    sqlite3 -cmd ".timeout 99999" /home/$pathOnHost/RSS/RSS_DB.db "insert into rss_stuff values(\"$temp\");"
```

Seems like the two "eval" statements in the helper function are causing the problem!
When I run the bash script as "admin" in a terminal I have to use

```
    removeSpecialChars '$temp'
```

And when the script is launched via Apache2-->cgi-bin-->bash as user "www-data" I have to use

```
    removeSpecialChars "$temp"
```

When I run the script in the terminal with the " a bunch of error messages pop up but the data in the table is OK. If I replace it with ' no error messages in the terminal, good data in the db, however, via cgi-bin, etc. the data gets messed up....
I can live with the " and the error messages (for now) which I only see during testing. One fine day I'll fix it properly, I promise ;)
Thanx Dri372 for your support!!

Comment: Instead of using `eval`, you could use namerefs with `declare -n` to the same effect.